# how to trim text of richtextarea in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I have used "RichTextArea" in GWT. Now i want to trim the text of the richtextarea.gettext() when i am submitting the form.

But if i have only entered **spaces and enter key** in my textarea then richtextarea.gettext() will not going to trim it as it will convert them to **&nbsp and < br>**.

Any suggestion if there are only entered spaces and enter key in my textarea then on **trim** it should give me **blank string value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you get &nbsp and < br> is the correct value what you get from the RichTextArea because it supplies HTML.

Implement your own trim-method:

```
public String trim(String s) {

   String result = s.trim(); 
   String x = result.replaceAll("<br>", "");
   x = x.replaceAll("&nbsp", "");
   x = x.trim();
   if(x.equals("")) {
       return x;
   } else {
       return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks sam its working just i have to make changes is i have to use replaceAll() insted of replace()